# How do we define the norm of a block operator matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the block-operator matrix
$$
D = 
\begin{bmatrix}
D^{1,1} & D^{1,2} & \dots & D^{1,M} \\
D^{2,1} & D^{2,2} & \dots & D^{2,M} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D^{M,1} & D^{M,2} & \dots & D^{M,M}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where each block $D^{m,n}$ is an operator $D^{m,n}:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

What norm can we use for $D$? For example, can we define a norm here by simply taking the 'largest' block, i.e.,
$$
||D|| = \max_{p,q \in M} ||D^{p,q}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})}.
$$

Is this a valid norm?

Comment: I believe that if we take $\tilde{D} = (\|D_{ij} \|_{L^2})_{M\times M}$, then defining
$$
\|D\| := \|\tilde D\|_*
$$
for any submultiplicative matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_*$, then the resulting norm will be submultiplicative.  However, I don't think that we can make an "operator norm" in the usual sense by following this recipe.

Comment: The norm you defined will not be submultiplicative.  That is, we don't have
$$
\|D_1D_2\| \leq \|D_1\| \, \|D_2\|
$$

Comment: Of course we can take the norm of the corresponding operator from $L^2(\Bbb R^M)$ to $L^2(\Bbb R^M)$, but I take it that you're trying to avoid that definition.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ultimately I want to be able to have a norm that can be decomposed into norms of the individual blocks. One way I though of doing that was just to take the max over all the blocks.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  But I would be interested if you can suggest another suitable norm that allows me to decompose into norms of the individual blocks? I really have no idea about norms for block operator matrices.

Comment: What is a "suitable norm" in this contexts? What are you using this norm for?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually after looking at it again I think I can use the following product norm: $$\begin{align*}
|| D ||^2 & = \sup_{||\phi||_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}))^M}=1} ||D \phi||_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}))^M}^2 \\
& = \sup_{||\phi||_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}))^M}=1} \sum_{p=1}^M\sum_{q=1}^M ||D^{pq}\phi^q||_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}))^M}^2 \\
\end{align*},$$ where $\phi = (\phi^1,\dots,\phi^M)$ are each functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Your last expression is incorrect. The product norm is given by
$$
\|D\|^2 = \sup_{||\phi||_{(L^2(\mathbb{R}))^M}=1} \sum_{p=1}^M\left\| \sum_{q=1}^M D^{pq}\phi^q\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^2
$$